# AMpscript in a SMS from Salesforce Object

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, sms

I have to send a SMS with variable informations, which could be changed after entrance in Journey from a Lead Salesforce Object.

Only to clarify, this SMS is a part of a journey and the Entrance Event are the Lead Object data on Salesforce.

To do that we used the code below and after some tests, I realize that If I use only the MOBILE_NUMBER in the code, it works normally, but the Record may not be the right one, once that I can have more than one register in the Salesforce with the same MobileNumber:

```
%%[ 
Set @LeadId = [Lead:Id]

Set @Cel = MOBILE_NUMBER

Set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead','FirstName,Condicao_1_Mensalidade__c,Bolsa_de_Estudo__c,MobilePhone','MobilePhone','=',@Cel)

Set @Row = Row(@rs,1)

Set @Cond = Field(@Row,'Condicao_1_Mensalidade__c')

Set @Cel1 = MOBILE_NUMBER

Set @Rs1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead','FirstName,Condicao_1_Mensalidade__c,Bolsa_de_Estudo__c,MobilePhone','MobilePhone','=',@Cel1)

Set @Row1 = Row(@Rs1,1)

Set @Bolsa = Field(@Row1,'Bolsa_de_Estudo__c')

If @Cond == 'Isenção' then set @isento= 'isencao'

endif

]%%
```

If I use only the MOBILE_NUMBER in the code, it works normally, but what I need it’s something more unique, that’s why I use the ID to classify:

```
%%[ 
Set @LeadId = [Lead:Id]

Set @Cel = MOBILE_NUMBER

Set @rs = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead','FirstName,Condicao_1_Mensalidade__c,Bolsa_de_Estudo__c,MobilePhone','MobilePhone','=',@Cel,'Id','=',@LeadId)

Set @Row = Row(@rs,1)

Set @Cond = Field(@Row,'Condicao_1_Mensalidade__c')

Set @LeadId1 = [Lead:Id]

Set @Cel1 = MOBILE_NUMBER

Set @Rs1 = RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Lead','FirstName,Condicao_1_Mensalidade__c,Bolsa_de_Estudo__c,MobilePhone','MobilePhone','=',@Cel1,'Id','=',@LeadId1)

Set @Row1 = Row(@Rs1,1)

Set @Bolsa = Field(@Row1,'Bolsa_de_Estudo__c')

If @Cond == 'Isenção' then set @isento= 'isencao'

endif

]%%
```

The first code worked normally, but the second it’s not running, what I did wrong?

Comment: I think you forgot to post the code you mentioned in the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
Now i understand :D Only way I found to do that is to lookup entry event Data Extension first using `MOBILE_NUMBER`. So lets say you inject all newly created leads to the journey. In your entry Event DE you have fields like:
**Lead:ID**
**Lead:CreatedDate or Lead:LastModifiedDate** - if you're injecting new use Created,
 if changed use LastModified
**Lead:Phone**

```
set @mobileNumber = MOBILE_NUMBER
set @lookupRow = LookupOrderedRows('Entry event DE Name', 1, 'Lead:CreatedDate DESC', 'Lead:Phone', @mobileNumber)
/* Change CreatedDate to LastModifiedDate if you trigger on records changed */
if RowCount(@lookupRow) == 1 then
    set @leadID = Field(Row(@lookupRow, 1), 'Lead:ID')
    /* Do Some stuff*/
endif
```

This is not 100% error proof approach but it works ok for short journeys, journeys without re-entry anytime etc. If you'd share more info like what are injection rules, how long is your journey overall and can contact's re-enter I'd be able to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks fot the answer, but I think you don't understand what I need. I don't need to populate the Salesforce, but write the sms with the informations from Salesforce.